# Exception java.lang.ClassCastException when query contacts

Tags: java, android

I was trying to get the contacts using a query through the ContactsContract
The following code throws an exception.
java.lang.ClassCastException.

```
public class ContactManager extends Activity{

    ArrayList<String> contactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] contacts = getContactNames();
    }

        public String[] getContactNames(){
            try{
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 

              contactsList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }
        return (String []) contactsList.toArray();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("WOw", e.toString());
            return null;
    }
        }
        }
```

Any idea?
I did not forget to add the permission

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the stack trace and to indicate the line that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `toArray()` returns an array of `Object` and it cannot be cast to an array of `String`.

You have to provide an argument to the method to specify the type :

```
return (String[]) contactsList.toArray(new String[contactsList.size()]);
```

You will find more details in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).